# All simple planar graphs have a vertex of degree at most $5$ (wheel of $n>5$).

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Lemma 7.13 All simple planar graphs have a vertex of degree at most 5.

I just read this lemma... wont this lemma fail on wheel of n>5 or am I missing something?

Wheel Graphs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the meaning "wheel of $n \geq 5$" ?

Comment: @Digitallis
here is a reference to wheel graphs
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph

Comment: Your lemma says that all simple planar graphs have _some_ vertex of degree at most $5$, not that _all_ vertices are of degree at most $5$.

Comment: @terran Oh I got played with  the words... I see now... Thanks 